# Return correct time measurements from a date

Tags: c#, datetime

I would like a method that returns a string from date that looks like the ones in the social media websites and forum .

Examples

- Added 2 seconds ago
- Added 3 mintues ago
- Added two weeks ago
- Added a month ago

and so on

I pass it a `DateTime` object and it returns a string based on the difference between `currentDate` and date passed to the method.

I know how to use timespan to get difference between dates but how can switch from seconds to minutes to hours to days to weeks appropriately?

For example if the difference between dates is 120 minutes I do not want it to return it 120 minutes, I want it to return 2 hours.

How to make this switch?

I would prefer a custom method in order to change the language of the string to Arabic. Can language be changed using libraries?

Thanks
Abdullah

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: I would like an advancement payable to me asap if I answer this simple question for you.. what have you actually done and or tried.. also please read the following [How To Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: I know how to use TimeSpan to get the difference but how to set the limit using seconds and switch to mintues. This is where i need help

Comment: `help` would imply you have posted code which gives us a starting point.

Comment: Take a look at the momentjs library or the livestampjs library - I think you'll find what you need there.

Comment: @AbdullahAlhutami if you are familiar with what you say the you should be familiar with the following `TimeSpan Duration` property and if you create an instance of TimeSpan object then you can get at the following for example 
`ts.Duration().Days 
ts.Duration().Hours 
ts.Duration().Minutes
ts.Duration().Seconds` as well as `tx.Days, ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds`

Comment: @MethodMan Yes i am familiar with that but how/when to let it choose what to return based on difference value. For example if the difference between dates is 120 mintues i do not want it to return it 120 mintues i want it to return 2 hours . how to make this switch ?

Comment: check this out for starters and there are several examples on SO as well I actually used one today and it worked most amazingly http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an overly simplified example of what you could do, using only .NET classes:

```
public static string TimeSinceEvent(DateTime eventTime)
{
    TimeSpan timeSince = DateTine.Now - eventTime;
    if (timeSince.Hours > 0)
        return string.Format("Added {0} hours ago", timeSince.Hours);
    else if (timeSince.Minutes > 0)
        return string.Format("Added {0} minutes ago", timeSince.Minutes);
    else 
        return string.Format("Added {0} seconds ago", timeSince.Seconds);
}
```

Of course, you could add more cases to handle days, months, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In C# there is a library called Humanizer that does it for you.

Humanizer also support many languages, you can see all languages here: https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer/tree/dev/src/Humanizer.Tests.Shared/Localisation.

Btw it already support Arabic.

See the example below

```
DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-30).Humanize() => "yesterday"
DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-2).Humanize() => "2 hours ago"

DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(30).Humanize() => "tomorrow"
DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2).Humanize() => "2 hours from now"

DateTimeOffset.AddHours(1).Humanize() => "an hour from now"
```

To use that, just install this package with nuget

```
Install-Package Humanizer
```

Then use it

```
var displayString = string.Format("Added {0}", myObj.Date.Humanize());
```

C# 6 syntax

```
var displayString = $"Added {myObj.Date.Humanize()";
```

If you want to build your own code, Humanizer is Open Source, you can check their source code and create your own.

https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer

Comment: Why would you use an external library for something so simple, integrated in the framework itself?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath this is not integrated in .NET Framework. Also Humanizer is a very powerfull library and handle many other things, not just datetime.

Comment: By saying that, I referred to the point that DateTime is extremely simple to work with, and a simple method could do this easily. I still don't see the point in adding a 3rd party library (which, by the way, would not be easy if working in an enterprise environment)

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I work in enterprise environment and its allowed here, anyway if you don't like third party library, its up to you, and I respect. But I don't like to reinvent wheel

Comment: I really envy you. My company policies tell us that we can't use libraries not developed by Microsoft (like NuGet packages by MS) or third-party libraries that are paid for, and this, believe me, is not possible to get easily.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath So you can use JSON.NET or JIL? Or Dapper?

Comment: The only thing I can use in the project I'm right now, is Aspose.Cells. And we got it because our web service depends heavily on Excel automation, and would be near to impossible otherwise.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I fell sad for you, in my team we can decide what we want to use, with C# version, and many other things. The last package that I added in my project is Akka.net that I am using to build a BackOffice, to run background workers for my application

Comment: @cFrozenDeath its financial management system that is hosted on AWS, www.coremanager.com.br its in portuguese. We are free to make our choices

Comment: Guys please try to help if its simple as you say @cFrozenDeath

Comment: @AbdullahAlhutami my answer doesn't solve?